# How to label multiple plots using predefined range

Tags: python, plot, label

I want to plot multiple signals in one figure and label them according to the predefined range.

This is the beginning of the code. I put some random values for the arrays `tot_voltage` and for `x`, because the real ones are too big.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shot_min= 1
shot_max = 4
shot_range = range(shot_min, shot_max)

tot_voltage = np.array([[ 0.00140459,   0.000847097,    0.000388473,    0.000223704],
[0.000415936,   -4.54262e-05,   0.000577968,    0.000638384],
[-0.000237666,  0.000836115,    0.000229195,    0.000336297],
[-0.00045187,   0.00135515, 0.000566982,    0.000523042],
[-0.000179999,  0.000448897,    0.00120137, 0.000998143],
[0.000127584,   0.00027588, -0.000350259,   0.00130298]])

x=np.array([-1.8401, -1.84, -1.8399, -1.8398, -1.8397, -1.8396])
```

Now I want to plot the data and put labels according to the `shot_range`. But this syntax is invalid and I don't know how to fix it.

```py
for i in range(0, len(tot_voltage[1,:])):
        y=tot_voltage[:,i]*1e3
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(x, y,  label = 'shot {}'.format(for i in shot_range)) 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```